# gHydraulic plugin for QGIS 2.8 make EPANET Model Type Error

Tags: qgis, plugins

I've set up my water network layers to create an EPANET model using the gHydraulics plugin for QGIS 2.8: pipes, junctions, and a reservoir. The pipes have unique IDs, with their corresponding junctions' IDs as Node 1 and Node 2. When trying to make the EPANET model, however, I get a Python error:

```
TypeError: qgis._core.QgsMapLayerRegistry cannot be instantiated or sub-classed
```

This does not happen with QGIS 2.0.

Comment: You can try giswater (http://www.giswater.org/) for windows (XP and Linux are not supported). It works well with QGIS 2.8. Download the testing version of Giswater **all-in-one installer** (you don't need Postgres+Postgis installed in your system). The EPANET USER'S GUIDE is in: http://www.giswater.org/documentation/chapter3.

Answer (score 2):

problem solved here: http://sourceforge.net/p/ghydraulic/bugs/32/
by Jorge Almério

in GHydraulicsModelMaker.py replace

`maplayers = QgsMapLayerRegistry().instance().mapLayers()`

with

`maplayers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()`